# Password from Key and Hash

Tags: powershell, passwords, securestring

I am trying to get the key this key for an assignment I was provided with the key and hash. In PowerShell how do I convert this to plain text. Any guidance is appreciated.

I have tried these

```
PS C:\test> $PlainPassword = Get-Content C:\test\secure-hash.txt

PS C:\test> $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $PlainPassword -AsPlainText -Force

PS C:\test>
```

I've tried `ConvertFrom-SecureString` input hash with no success

Comment: If you're using a Key then it's missing an argument

Comment: What I am missing? I was provided with the key and the hash but I am new to powershell So I am not sure what I am missing. Can you please provide guidance?

Comment: I can show you the process of exporting and importing a password using a Key if that helps not sure if that's exactly what you have right now

Comment: Please if you don't mind that would be great. Would that generate the plain text password if I have they key and the hash? What do you need from me? Would it be ok to post key and hash here? My apologies what is the actual process?

Answer (score 0):

The process of exporting and importing a Password using the [`-Key` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7.3#-key) goes like this:

1. You need to generate a Key, for that you can use the [`RandomNumberGenerator` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-7.0). **Note: Valid key lengths are 16, 24 and 32 bytes.**

```bash
$key = [byte[]]::new(32)
$ran = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()
$ran.GetBytes($key)

# Export the new key to a file:
Export-Clixml -InputObject $key -Path path\to\myKey.key
```

2. Export your password using this key.

```bash
# Import the key (it should be obtained from a Vault preferably)
$key = Import-CliXml path\to\myKey.key

$myPassWord = 'myPassword'
ConvertTo-SecureString $myPassWord -AsPlainText -Force |
    ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key |
    Set-Content path\to\myPassword.txt
```

3. Lastly you can import it whenever you want using the same key.

If you're using PowerShell Core:

```bash
# Get the encrypted password
$encryptedPassword = Get-Content path\to\myPassword.txt -Raw
# Import the key (it should be obtained from a Vault preferably)
$key = Import-CliXml path\to\myKey.key

ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedPassword -Key $key |
    ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
# -> Outputs: `myPassword`
```

If you're using Windows PowerShell:

```bash
# Get the encrypted password
$encryptedPassword = Get-Content path\to\myPassword.txt -Raw
# Import the key (it should be obtained from a Vault preferably)
$key = Import-CliXml path\to\myKey.key

$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedPassword -Key $key
[System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $secureString).Password
# -> Outputs: `myPassword`
```

Comment: Step 1 $secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedPassword -Key $key
Step 2 [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $secureString).Password
Resulets # -> Outputs: `myPassword`

Comment: I get the following ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At line:1 char:40
+ $secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedPassword -Key $key

Comment: @AliONE you're missing the part where you read the content of the files using `Get-Content`. Please, re-read the answer.

Comment: You really need to learn the basics of powershell to even understand the help you are provided. Gotta crawl before you walk.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that worked! I was missing a statement. Thank you. Santiago I appreciate the patience and the help. Doug Maurer. For sure. I am learning.