# Unable to bind parameter Key to ConvertTo-SecureString

Tags: powershell

I am getting error when trying to bind argument to parameter ConvertTo-SecureString. Error refers to it as null.

CODE:

```
param (
    [string]$NewPassword
)
$key = "ThisIsMyEncryptionKey1234"
$encryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $NewPassword -Key $key
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $env:USERNAME -NewPassword $encryptedPassword -Reset
$path = "n:\logs\pwtracker.txt"
$encryptedPassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $path -Append
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind parameter 'Key'. Cannot convert value "ThisIsMyEncryptionKey1234" to type "System.Byte". Error:
"Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:63
+ $encryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $NewPassword -Key $key
+                                                               ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
```

Comment: `-Key` expects a byte array not a string. Assuming `$key` is actually the key used to encrypt your password, then you need to tell us in which format did you stored it? Could it be base64?

Comment: Yes Key should be key to use encrypt that password. I am not sure what format UTF8 or base64 are for ad passwords?

Comment: I not sure I understand your question. How can we know how it was decided to store that key?

Comment: I will be using hard coded key to encrypt password that I am storing in the text file. I don't think I explained that correctly.

Comment: Right and how did you stored in the text file? Did you just store it as raw bytes? Did you encoded the bytes as base64 before storing it? Because I would like to assume your line of code `$key = "ThisIsMyEncryptionKey1234"` is not actually hardcoded right? You're reading the key from a file which we're currently not seeing

Comment: No, I didn't stored in the file. I have this wrong as you noted simple a string. I did some more digging and come up with this: $key = [System.Text.Encoding]::base64.GetBytes('&F)H@McQfTjWnZr4') , and so now this is the error You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $key = [System.Text.Encoding]::base64.GetBytes('&F)H@McQfTjWnZr4')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Here, look at this answer to give you an idea of how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74935934/15339544

Comment: Thanks for the link! Is there a way to use hardcoded key instead of creating one as they mentioned in the article? I don't need random keys just one that will encrypt password created?

Comment: So why do you want to use a key to encrypt the passwords? Is this file "n:\logs\pwtracker.txt" supposed to be read by someone else than you? You can use a hardcoded key in your script but at that point mind as well store the passwords as plain text since what you're doing is not secure at all

Comment: Well that file should store all password that are changed. So I don't want other users to see plain text passwords. That's right. This is just for administrative purposes when we made changes of all password we get rid of that file.

Comment: So what you should do, assuming the key is meant to be shared, use the method shown in the linked answer to generate a random byte array, then you can do `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)` and store that key ideally in a vault, somewhere safe, after you have that key stored, in your script you can read it and do `$key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($storedKey)` and use it in your code. It should work after following those steps.

Answer (score 1):

##upd

```
 $NewPassword = read-host "password" -AsSecureString 

function GetKey(){
    
$AESKey = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($AESKey)
$AESKey



}
$SecPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $NewPassword -AsPlainText -Force    
$AESKey = GetKey
$AESKey | out-file "$PSScriptRoot\password_aes.key"

$encryptedPassword  = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $SecPass -Key $AESKey
$encryptedPassword | out-file "$PSScriptRoot\encryptedPassword.txt"
```

reverse decryption

```
$key = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\password_aes.key"
$SecPassString = $PSScriptRoot\encryptedPassword.txt"
$SecPass = $SecPassString | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
```

Comment: I've tried this and got this error: ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:35
+ $SecPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $NewPassword -AsPlainText -Force
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStrin
   gCommand

Comment: Also this is missing the whole Set-AdAccountPassword statement.

Comment: @JerryP Are you serious? This is part of your script, you have exactly the same parameter. I thought you would embed my answer in your script.